# Exception is not being caught with its name but it is caught when others keyword is used?

Tags: exception, ada

Exception is not being caught with its name but it is caught when others keyword is used? Below is my code

p.ads

```
 package p is 
  procedure proc ;
  end p;
```

p.adb

```
  package body p is
   my_exp:exception; -- user define exception
   procedure proc is
   begin
    raise my_exp; -- spreading exception
   end proc;
   end p;
```

p_main.adb

```
with p;
 with ada.text_io;
 use ada.text_io;
use p;
procedure p_main is
 begin
   proc;
  exception
when my_exp=>put(" my_exp");-- error but when others is used then.its good why?
  end p_main;
```

A/c to adacore site my_exp is not visible here then how it is visible when others keyword is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has numerous syntax errors. It's always better to copy-and-paste your *exact* code into the question; you appear to have re-typed it, which makes it difficult to distinguish between typos and actual errors in your original code.

Ignoring the syntax errors, this:

```
exception
    when my_exp => put(" my_exp");
```

fails to compile because the name `my_exp` is not visible. (If you want it to be visible it should be in the package specification, but that's not what you asked.)

If you replace `when my_exp` by `when others`, it works; the exception is handled.  This is because a `when others` clause handles *any* exception that's been raised, whether its name is visible or not.

An exception is a condition that exists when a program is running. The exception handler detects and handles that run-time entity. It doesn't need to refer to it by whatever identifier you used to define it.

If the name `my_exp` had been visible, the handler *still* (almost certainly) wouldn't use the name to identify the exception. Instead, the compiler creates some run-time data structure that allows exceptions to be identified, perhaps by a reference to a specific memory address. The exact mechanism depends on the compiler, and understanding the details is not terribly important unless you're writing a compiler.

The run-time detection that an exception has been raised, and which exception it is, does not depend on the name you've assigned to the exception in your source code.

The reference to the name `my_exp` is rejected *at compile time* because that name is not visible at compile time.

Comment: i m totally agree with u but still had some doubt that if exception is not visible then how 'others' clause can catch exception? and you said that if the name 'my_exp' had been visible, the handler still (almost certainly) wouldn't use the name to identify the exception but when i kept 'my_exp:exception' in spec in ads file then using its name 'when my_exp' exception is caught?Can you please explain?

Comment: @yes: Names like `my_exp` are resolved by the compiler. The (mostly) do not exist while the program is running. The `when others` handler doesn't depend on the (compile-time) name of the exception; it handles *any* exception. The compiler generates whatever code is needed to make that happen.

Comment: but in my case if my_exp is moved to spec file then   by using its name my_exp it is able to catch ?

Comment: @yes: Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is that if your package can raise a custom exception which isn't advertised by the package specification, that is bad design because it leads to unpleasant surprises for the package users.

So the right thing to do is to declare `my_exp` in the package instead of hiding it in the body.

```
package p is 
   my_exp:exception; -- user define exception

   procedure proc ;
end p;
```

And then fix all the other trivial syntax errors, and your program works as advertised.

But even if you don't, and "my_exp" is not visible in the main program, its exception handler can identify it correctly.

```
procedure p_main is
begin
   proc;
end p_main;
```

./p_main
raised P.MY_EXP : p.adb:7

Or you can manipulate that information yourself, for better diagnostics or error recovery

```
with Ada.Exceptions;  -- we need to process exception data

procedure p_main is
begin
   proc;
exception
   when  E : others => 
      put("something bad happened : " & Ada.Exceptions.Exception_Name(E));
end p_main;
```

./p_main
something bad happened : P.MY_EXP